# Remove focus from all Edit Text after click on OK from Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, highlight

My Activity contain three EditText and one button.
I set custom AlertBox for get the User input on one EditText.
When I click on OK button from Alert Box , Focus Automatically goes to First EditText.

I used

```
editext.clearFocus();
```

I also tried

```
editText.clearFocus();
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

But doesn't work.
How to remove focus in All EditText after click on OK from AlertDialog.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear focus and remove cursor from editText

```
editText.clearFocus();
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the root layout of your xml:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
public void clicked(View v)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Hello");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            editText.setFocusable(false);
        }
    });

    alert.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and it is working perfectly. On Clicking the option of submitting it will clear the focus and remove cursor on edit text.

```
getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();
```