# tap outside edittext to lose focus in dialog fragment

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, dialog

I'd like to have my edittext lose focus and close the keyboard when clicking outside of it. I've found some really nice answers to this question that work for activities but I can't seem to figure it out inside my dialog fragment. I'm using a separate class to hold my alert dialog builder, something like this:

```
 private EditText etProject;

 @NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_retro_add_work,null);

    etProject = v.findViewById(R.id.edittext_project_name);
    builder.setView(v)
    return builder.create();
```

Comment: Try `builder.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: You need to detect touches (_on Touch Listener_) outside of the edittext and then remove the focus from edittext (like in this [Remove Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305946/remove-focus-from-all-edit-text-after-click-on-ok-from-alert-dialog)).